What is the correct way to install a plugin for CKEditor 5 in case I don't use Node Package Manager and also don't want to install a contrib module?
I wish to install the CKEditor 5 plugin Word Count.
It is noted in the README of this plugin that it should be done with Node Package Manager (npm) but I don't use it and not sure if I must use it in case I work with Drupal 10.3 and up.
What is the correct way to install a plugin for CKEditor 5 in case I don't use Node Package Manager and also don't want to install a contrib module for this?
I can of course download the entire CKEditor 5 zip from GitHub, extract this plugin, upload it to Drupal directory /libraries/ckeditor5/word-count and then configure, but primarily for the sake of knowledge, is there or should there be another way?

The correct way is you manage your project's dependencies with Composer and install NPM libraries with Asset Packagist. See for example how it's done in drupal-composer/drupal-project's composer.json:
In the repositories section add Asset Packagist:
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ],

This will allow you to have NPM packages being downloaded to your project's vendor/ directory via command $ composer require npm-asset/ckeditor--ckeditor5-word-count
But you need it in your web/libraries/ directory and not in your vendor/ directory.
In the require section you add composer/installers and oomphinc/composer-installers-extender via command $ composer require composer/installers oomphinc/composer-installers-extender:
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^2.1",
        ..
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2.0",
        ..

And configure installer-types and installer-paths in the extra section to take care of putting the libraries into the right directory.
    "extra": {
        ..
        "installer-paths": {
            ..
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library",
                "type:bower-asset",
                "type:npm-asset"
            ],
            ..
        },
        "installer-types": [
            "bower-asset",
            "npm-asset"
        ],
        ..

